# Add datepickers dateformat to dynamically generated textbox, where dateformat is set as attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have generated textbox dynamically from code behind, a class "DateTextBox" is set to all the textbox controls generated dynamically. 
A datepicker control is set to the class, but each text control requires a different date format. How can i set the date format for each textbox's DatePicker ??

the dynamically generated textbox control html ->

```
<input type="text" class="DateTextBox" data-dateformat='dd/mm/yy'>
</br>
<input type="text" class="DateTextBox" data-dateformat='dd/MM/yy'>
</br>
<input type="text" class="DateTextBox" data-dateformat='d/M/yy'>
</br>
<input type="text" class="DateTextBox" data-dateformat='d/MM/yy'>
```

the datepicker jquery ->

```
$('.DateTextBox').datepicker({ dateFormat: $(this).attr('data-dateformat'),
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
```

check jsFiddler

http://jsfiddle.net/khlakhil/av970gor/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to iterate with `each` to create a scope where `this` really does reference each element

```
$('.DateTextBox').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ 
            dateFormat      : $(this).data('dateformat'),
            showButtonPanel : true,
            changeMonth     : true,
            changeYear      : true,
            defaultDate     : new Date(),
            changeMonth     : true,
            changeYear      : true
     });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/av970gor/2/)